# Multiple definition with Protobuffer 3.7.1 generated files

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, protobuf-c

I try to compile some protocol-buffer files and I am getting the following errors.

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lattice_planner.dir/modules/control/proto/lat_controller_conf.pb.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable lattice_planner
CMakeFiles/lattice_planner.dir/modules/localization/proto/pose.pb.cc.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `apollo::localization::_Pose_default_instance_'
CMakeFiles/lattice_planner.dir/modules/common/localization/proto/pose.pb.cc.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
CMakeFiles/lattice_planner.dir/modules/localization/proto/pose.pb.cc.o: In function `apollo::localization::Pose::Pose()':
pose.pb.cc:(.text+0x4e8): multiple definition of `apollo::localization::Pose::Pose()'
CMakeFiles/lattice_planner.dir/modules/common/localization/proto/pose.pb.cc.o:pose.pb.cc:(.text+0x4e8): first defined here
```

The files are in different folders. Can I trick the compiler GCC 5.4.0 so that there are not multiple definitions? 
The CMakeLists.txt is quite huge because I added all source files by hand. Here are some code snippets:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(lattice_planner_src)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++11 -pthread")
find_package(Protobuf 3.7.1 REQUIRED)
if(PROTOBUF_FOUND)
    message ("log: protobuf found")
else()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Protobuf")
endif()

add_executable(lattice_planner  apollo-planner-test-main.cpp  ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${PTB_SRC} ${PTB_HDR})

target_include_directories (
    lattice_planner
    PUBLIC
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
    /usr/local/include/qpOASES
    ${TinyXML2_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${IPOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ctpl
)

target_link_libraries(lattice_planner
#    EIGEN
    ${TinyXML2_LIBRARIES}
#    ${GLOG_LIBRARY}
    ${IPOPT_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
    /usr/local/lib/libglog.so.0
    /usr/local/lib/libqpOASES.a
    ${libgtest}
)
```

while the `PTB_SRC` and `PTB_HDR` are the protocol-buffer sources and headers. This project is already running on windows with MS projects. Unfortunately,  I don't have any CMake for that. I am also happy for ideas and guesses.

Comment: Simple, but ugly trick is to add `inline` keyword to functions. This won't work with variables tho. Best solution would be to fix multiple symbol definition - change all but one definitions of every symbol to declaration and you will be fine.

Comment: In overall, there are 180 headers and 180 source files. I hope there will be a better solution.

Comment: It seems you have two proto files defining messages with the same name in the same namespace. This is, shall we say, unwise. Are you the author of these proto files?

Comment: It is from the Baidu Apollo project.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski  `inline`  does not work bad.